# Upgrade to Yosemite failed - MBR and GPT don't match?

Tags: macos, upgrade, partition

Upgrading to Yosemite so I can install the newest version of xCode.
Shortly after starting I get this error:

[image: A mismatch between the MBR and GPT partition maps is not supported with this operation. Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again.]

I've tried going into Disk Utility and repairing permissions, but even though it says it's repairing things, when I run it again the same errors show up.

Not sure what to do here.

Edit: Disk Manager

[image]

Edit 2: GPT and FDisk:

[image]

Edit 3: in response to n1000

```
Command (? for help): v

Warning! Mismatched GPT and MBR partition! MBR partition 4, of type 0x07,
has no corresponding GPT partition! You may continue, but this condition
might cause data loss in the future!

Identified 1 problems!

Command (? for help): ?
b   back up GPT data to a file
c   change a partition's name
d   delete a partition
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   list known partition types
n   add a new partition
o   create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
r   recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s   sort partitions
t   change a partition's type code
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
b   use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
c   load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
d   use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
e   load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
f   load MBR and build fresh GPT from it
g   convert GPT into MBR and exit
h   make hybrid MBR
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   load partition data from a backup file
m   return to main menu
o   print protective MBR data
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
t   transform BSD disklabel partition
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu
```

Comment: so you are able to boot your previous system right now?

Comment: What are you upgrading from and how is the disk partitioned?  What OSes are installed if more then whatever version of OS X you're trying to upgrade from? Are you running a third party boot manager?

Comment: @user3439894 Upgrading from 10.9.5. I have a bootcamp partition with windows 8.1 on it. I'm just using the boot manager that came with the OS. I'm adding a screenshot of disk manager

Comment: @n1000 Yeah, I was able to quit the installer and choose to boot to the old OS.

Comment: Please add to the OP the output of the following two commands in aTerminal. Copy and paste as one command then press Enter: `sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0; sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`

Comment: @user3439894 Ok, done

Comment: Is the some reason you had to post a graphics image instead of just copying and pasting the output from the Terminal?  Although without proper output from the `gpt` command it's somewhat moot.

Comment: @user3439894 Uploading the image was just easier. The output from the terminal formatting was getting messed up when I put it in as text. What am I doing wrong with the gpt command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3467) explains the procedure. **Now is probably a good time to make a backup. *Then proceed at your own risk...***

1. Get [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/download.html)
2. In Terminal: `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`
3. Press `v` to verify your MBR
4. Press `r` and then `o` to list the MBR partition table
5. Press `m` and then `p` to display the GPT partition table information
6. Compare the numbers for partition 4 from the MBR and GPT tables. The start numbers should match, but the end numbers will probably be off.
7. Press `d` to delete the GPT partition 4 (Bootcamp). "*Note: this does not delete the actual partition from disk. It only deletes gdisk's in-memory representation of the GPT.*"
8. Press `n` to create a new partition 4 (Bootcamp) **using the start and end sector values from the MBR partition 4**
9. Change the name of the new partition 4 to BOOTCAMP
10. Press `v` to verify
11. **If no errors occurred**: press `w` to write the new partition table
12. **If errors occurred**: press `q` and try again
13. Reboot

The important part is step 7 where you sync your GPT and MBR. Note that some of the commands (e.g. disk0, partition 4) may be different in your case. Please adapt them accordingly.

Comment: Before doing this make sure you are properly backed up! :)

Comment: @user3439894 good point :)

Comment: With step 4, `r` takes you into `recovery and transformation options (experts only)` mode, and step 5 `m` takes you back into normal mode. I posted the output of `v`, as well as the two help menus in case what I downloaded is different than what you have...

Comment: Figured it out. Steps 4 and 5 were missing the parts where print tables was actually chosen, instead of just entering the menu and then leaving it again. I updated the instructions to put the necessary commands.

Comment: @AndyD273 Does that mean you were able to upgrade to Yosemite? Great!

Comment: Yup! I was just getting hung up with showing the tables `o` and `p`. I kept deleting the partition and then putting the wrong numbers from `p` back in, instead of the correct numbers from `o`. Took me a little bit to figure out what I was doing wrong, and then it just worked.

Comment: @AndyD273 Feel free to edit the answer or let me know how to improve it.

Comment: Already edited it. You were missing a couple steps from the link you posted '[This post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3467)', so I just fixed steps 4 and 5 and put in a new 6 to explain what to look for. For future people with the same problem, just in case the Apple forum thread ever disappears.